# decision boundary in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I was reading the following sample problem on http://nlp.stanford.edu/
[image]

"Consider building an SVM over the (very little) data set shown in Figure. Working geometrically, for an example like this, the maximum margin weight vector will be parallel to the shortest line connecting points of the two classes, that is, the line between (1,1) and (2,3), giving a weight vector of (1,2). The optimal decision surface is orthogonal to that line and intersects it at the halfway point. Therefore, it passes through (1.5,2). So, the SVM decision boundary is:

y = x_1 + 2x_2 - 5.5"

Can anybody kindly explain to me how we have got this equation? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is perpendicular to the line between (1,1) and (2,3), and pass their center ((1+2)/2,(1+3)/2). Thus such line will achieve the maximum margin and separate (1,1) and (2,3).

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood as well; I was actually wondering about the "-5.5" in the equation. How have we calculated that??? Thank you for your time.

Comment: When you have a point on this line, the distance from the point to this line should be 0, so (1+2)/2,(1+3)/2*2-c=0 ---> c=5.5. If the point is not on the line, the distance will be y.

Comment: oh man, thanks a lot pal. How on earth have I missed that. Anyway, thanks a lot pal for your help. Cheers :)

Comment: extremely sorry to bother you again, but can you kindly confirm me about the weight vector i.e. in this case, it is (1,2). Have we got it by (2-1,3-1)???

Comment: yes. actually x2/x1=(3-1)/(2-1)=2, but since your new line is orthogonal to the line between 1,1 and 2,3, x2_new/x1_new=-1/2, that's where the weight vector comes from

Answer (score 0):

A(1,1), B(2,3)

⃗=(2,3)−(1,1)=(,2)

g(1,1) = -1; A : a + 2a + 0=−1 …①

g(2,3) =  1; B : 2a + 6a + 0=1 …②

② ; 0=1-8a

② substituted to ① ; 3a + 1 -8a = -1

a=2/5, 0=−11/5

⃗=(2/5,4/5) …>support vector

( ⃗ )=(2/5,4/5)(_1,_2 )+(−11/5)
( ⃗ )=_1+2_2−5.5

I hope it helps.